# Error parsing RSA public key

Tags: go, rsa

I'm trying to read an RSA public key from file with the following code:

```
keyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("pubkey.pem")
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
block, _ := pem.Decode(keyBytes)
fmt.Printf("block.Type: %s\n", block.Type)
pubkeyInterface, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
pubkey, ok := pubkeyInterface.(*rsa.PublicKey)                                                 
if !ok {
  log.Fatal("Fatal error")
}
cipher, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(nil, pubkey, []byte(msg))                                   
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x463921]

goroutine 1 [running]:
io.ReadAtLeast(0x0, 0x0, 0xc200089002, 0x70, 0x7e, ...)
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/io/io.go:284 +0xf1
io.ReadFull(0x0, 0x0, 0xc200089002, 0x70, 0x7e, ...)
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/io/io.go:302 +0x6f
crypto/rsa.nonZeroRandomBytes(0xc200089002, 0x70, 0x7e, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/crypto/rsa/pkcs1v15.go:134 +0x70
crypto/rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(0x0, 0x0, 0xc20004c550, 0xc20004c560, 0xd, ...)
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/crypto/rsa/pkcs1v15.go:35 +0x236
main.encode(0x536630, 0xd, 0x535ad0, 0x9, 0x54f1b0, ...)
    /home/taot/programming/go/encrypt/read_cert.go:28 +0x355
main.main()
    /home/taot/programming/go/encrypt/read_cert.go:12 +0x32

goroutine 2 [syscall]:

goroutine 3 [runnable]:
```

Seems something is wrong with my type assertion converting interface{} to *rsa.PublicKey, but I didn't get a compile error.

What's the correct way of doing this?  Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Terry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because you're passing nil to `rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15`. As the first parameter it needs an `io.Reader` from which to read random bytes. You can use, for example, `rand.Reader` from package `crypto/rand`.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out that... Thanks a lot!
May I ask why we would need to pass in some random bytes? Is it for padding or something?

Comment: Wow, you are quick!  But what's the purpose of the random bytes?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with PKCS but it seems you're supposed to encrypt a message smaller than the public key size. The message seems to be padded to the length of the key with non-zero random bytes.

Comment: @ctn: Not only smaller but also the data you encrypt **MUST** be random-like (it **MUST NOT** have a predetermined format) or you will leak private key information. That's why security algorithms usually encrypt a randomly-generated key that is then used to encipher the cleartext with a symmetric algorithm.